# Web Api - Receive a request and wait for a response from client in c#

Tags: c#, .net, webapi

Is it possible on a web api to receive a request ([HttpGet]), send a notification with SignalR to a client (Windows client) and wait for the client to response, and, only after receive the response from the client, send data from who requested o HttpGet inicial?

Example:

1) Someone asks for data from the Web Api (HTTPGET), for example, the customer's latest sales;

2) The web api through signalR asks a "Windows client" to provide the requested data;

3) The web api waits for the data to be sent (ex: client X) by the "Windows Client";

4) Only when the web api receives data from, eg, "client X", return the result to whom made the initial request (point "1").

Comment: it sounds like you just want to stream the result from the windows client to the actual client (http) via signalr which is totally doable no need for multiple requests or anything

Comment: bturner1273: yes, but I need a light! But I have no idea to implement my vision!

Comment: Instead of all this complicated back and forth, why not just have the client submit the requested data with the initial request?

Comment: I will try to explain: I have a Windows VB6 application and I have a Windows service that receives SignalR requests from a Wep Api, and this Windows Service "inform" the VB6 application that has notifications. My goal was wait the "data" to be sent by sent by VB6 application and then, send it to the first request that was made on the web api. Thanks!